# Android pdf library support highlighting

Tags: android, pdf

I want to integrate pdf reading functionality in my Android application. I came a cross a lot of available libs like :

APV           - slow

VUDROID       - slow

DRIOD READER  - faster

PdfViewer.jar - faster

I couldn't find in the docs of any of them if there is a support for highlighting. Also the first two libs are so slow. Is there any suitable library that's good from performance prospective and also support highlighting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [MuPDF](http://mupdf.com/docs/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android). It's very fast! :-)

For the higlighting you can check the class [MuPDFView.java](http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=mupdf.git;a=blob;f=platform/android/src/com/artifex/mupdfdemo/MuPDFView.java); look at the method:

```
public boolean markupSelection(Annotation.Type type);
```

There is also a demo Activity [MuPDFActivity](http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=mupdf.git;a=blob;f=platform/android/src/com/artifex/mupdfdemo/MuPDFActivity.java) where you can learn how to implement all supported types of annotations etc.